# JavaScript How to get a list of global Function name in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I want to find all Function named goXXXXGridSearch and change it's behavior.
It works on Chrome but can't work on IE8.
because the 'for in window' on IE8 didn't show the function I had defined.
How could I make it work on IE8.

This is my code:

```
$(function(){
    var re = /(go)+\w+(GridSearch)/;
    for(var fn in window) {
        if(re.test(fn)) {
            var target = window[fn];
            window[fn] = function(){
                loading(true);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    target.apply(window, arguments);
                    loading(false);
                }, 500);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code, not pictures of code

Comment: What does IE8 show in the console (remember to open the console first before using console.log)

Comment: IE8 console only show the property and function defined in window Object

Comment: http://seanmonstar.com/post/708979238/iterating-global-variables-in-internet-explorer

Comment: The idea in that link is good, but not work very well.That solution cause a out of memory error. I think it is because I using a huge ui lib on my page, all source code of the ui lib be readed in to one variable cause error. anyway thanks :)